# What are similar black and/or white permanents to Divine Visitation?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander, deck-building

For my Commander deck I'm looking for black and/or white permanents that have similar mechanics to [Divine Visitation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDivine%20Visitation%5d) and [Teysa Karlov](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeysa%20Karlov%5d), respectively:

> If one or more creature tokens would be created under your control, that many 4/4 white Angel creature tokens with flying and vigilance are created instead.

> Creature tokens you control have vigilance and lifelink.

I'm looking for cards to buff my tokens, preferably enchantments but creatures will also suffice. By "buff" I mean: increase the statistics and/or add keywords to the tokens. Similar to the cards above, but the buffs may vary.

---

As a sidenote: any tips on how I can conduct such research by myself––such as a website––is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Advanced Search on Gatherer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Advanced.aspx) may help a little.

For buffs that work when a creature enters the battlefield, search for ["creature enters the battlefield under your control"](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=%20[%22creature%20enters%20the%20battlefield%20under%20your%20control%22]&color=%20![R]%20![U]%20![G]).

E.g. [Cathars' Crusade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCathars%27%5d%2b%5bCrusade%5d):

> Whenever a creature enters the battlefield under your control, put a +1/+1 counter on each creature you control.

For permanent buffs, search for ["creatures you control get" or "creatures you control gain"](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&color=%20![R]%20![U]%20![G]&text=%7C[%22creatures%20you%20control%20get%22]%7C[%22creatures%20you%20control%20gain%22]):

E.g. [Benalish Marshal](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBenalish%20Marshal%5d):

> Other creatures you control get +1/+1.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already pointed out good abilities. I'll mention [Requiem Angel](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bRequiem%20Angel%5d), which states:

> When a non-spirit dies, you put a 1/1 spirit token into play instead.

When your [Divine Visitation](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDivine%20Visitation%5d) is on the battlefield, this effect is replaced by creating a 4/4 flying angel token instead. Since it's not a spirit, when *that* creature dies,  Requiem Angel's ability will trigger and create a new 4/4 angel in its place.

With [Teysa Karlov](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bTeysa%20Karlov%5d) out in addition to these cards, each time an angel dies your board creates two more angels.

Comment: This is an excellent combo piece! :)

Answer (score 1):

**The official online resource for searching cards is [Oracle](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Default.aspx).**

Gatherer is guaranteed to have the official wording of all magic cards and offers both simple and advanced filtering options.

> 108.1. Use the Oracle card reference when determining a card’s wording. A card’s Oracle text can be found using the Gatherer card database at Gatherer.Wizards.com.

As far as your question is concerned, assuming you are asking about Standard, here are a few searches to start you off:

["Creatures you control"](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[%22creatures%20you%20control%22]&format=+[%22Standard%22])

["Whenever a", creature, enter, battlefield](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&format=+[%22Standard%22]&text=+[%22whenever%20a%22]+[creature]+[enter]+[battlefield])

Comment: "For my Commander" not standard...

Comment: Then you can adjust the search and change the format to search in.

Answer (score 1):

There's an established Modern deck called [B/W tokens](http://bwtokens4life.com/index.php/2019/07/03/scg-invitational-june-8-2019/). It's not a top deck, but it's there.

Key token cards are:

- [Lingering Souls](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bLingering%20Souls%5d) - a powerful card, makes 4 flying tokens over two turns.
- [Spectral Procession](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpectral%20Procession%5d) - makes 3 tokens for 3 mana.
- [Intangible Virtue](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bIntangible%20Virtue%5d) - buffs all tokens.
- [Bitterblossom](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBitterblossom%5d) - makes tokens every turn.
- [Hidden Stockpile](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHidden%20Stockpile%5d) - same as above.

Other payoff cards include [Sorin, Solemn Visitor](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSorin%2c%20Solemn%20Visitor%5d), [Gideon, Ally of Zendikar](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGideon%2c%20Ally%20of%20Zendikar%5d) and [Zealous Persecution](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bZealous%20Persecution%5d). You could also run something like [Honor of the Pure](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHonor%20of%20the%20Pure%5d) if your tokens are white (warning: too many anthem effects can mean you open a hand with no threats, in which case all your anthems are dead).